# GridView Tutorial Fails To Compile

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement the GridView tutorial at:

```
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html
```

However, I get the error:

> ImageAdapter cannot be resolved to a type.

I am using Android 4.0 (API Level 4).

Googling for ImageAdapter does not find an official API description for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageAdapter is listed on the linked page as a custom class extending BaseAdapter.  If it cannot be resolved to a type, you have set up your project in such a way that the HelloGridView class cannot see the ImageAdapter class.

Make sure you have both ImageAdapter and HelloGridView in your project.

Comment: It still doesn't compile.  It complains that sample_0, sample_1, etc. "cannot be resolved or is not a field" for this line: `private Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3, ... };` and I have downloaded the sample images and copied them into `drawable`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, and `drawable-mdpi`.

Comment: I got it working.  I deleted and re-added the source and it started to work.  I've noticed this behaviour with Eclipse before.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to do that ?